# How to show multiple areas by location in google maps using php and sql

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have google position in data base like this value :-

```
(51.07912162794555, 9.67226742183027)
```

An i have more than one position in data base, my problem is i try to show all location in map, but the map not show, here is my code :-

```
<?PHP

$sqlallmap = mysql_query("select * from center where statusnow= 1 ");

while($rowsmap = mysql_fetch_array($sqlallmap) ) {

    $maps = $rowsmap ['gposition'];
    $maps = str_replace('(','',$maps);
    $maps = str_replace(')','',$maps);




}

?>
<style type="text/css">
#map_canvas { height: 330px; width: 550px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $maps; ?>);
var addressMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $maps; ?>);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 15,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
myOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map:map, position: addressMarker });
}

</script>


<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: A google.maps.LatLng takes two numbers, not a string.

Comment: How can show loop ?? its show me only one location